# Angular UI Router - Fire resolve function of parent state from child state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Is there a way to fire a resolve function of a parent state again, after i transitioned from a child state back to its parent state?

Think of a service which holds an array of objects.
For "security" reasons, my service only gives out copies of the objects it's holding, to prevent direct manipulation from the controllers.

The array of objects is retrieved from my backend and saved in the service, the first time i go to the parent state and is resolved to this parent view.

If i transition to a child state, my service hands out one object of this array to manipulate it. After manipulation, changes get saved by my service and the original array gets updated with the new manipulated object.

After this, i transition back to my parent state, but because of ui-routers nature, the resolve function isn't fired again. My parent state displays the old array instead of the updated one.

But of course, i want the new data loaded. I dont want to work with broadcasting events, or manually retrieving stuff from my controller (in this case). I can't use the `reload` param of ui-router because i need it to work on `window.history.back()` as well.

Any ideas how to solve this? I could get it working the way i want by not using nested states (no child states), but actually, thats not a real option.
So the only option i see at the moment, is not to work with copies in this case, instead just use references.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @antirealm No. Unfortunately not. Still interested in an answer though.